# how can I use vitamio player in android?

Tags: android, vitamio

I want to play some video in url with vitamio player but how I can do it.I install vitamio player in phone .(it says it is be default player but it do not play or open)

Comment: Please visit the website http://vitamio.org/ or download VitamioDemo from github https://github.com/yixia/VitamioDemo

Comment: Why don't you use webview for playing youtube flv files/links?

Comment: @vrossle Song I downloaded & tried above link code, but it throws "java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError" this error. Can you plz figure out this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you coding an app to use Vitamio as codec pack, or are you just simply trying to play a video? 
If you want to use Vitamio as your video player in an app, you need to download the Vitamio SDK from their website. Play around with the demo project and you'll understand how it works.